# jQuery Replace Value in Div

Tags: jquery, replace

I have some code like

```
var newName = 'Tom';
<div id="me">My name is {Name}</div>
```

How can I use jQuery to find and replace the `{Name}` with the var `newName` ?

Comment: The second line is not valid Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One-off solution:

```
var newName = 'Tom';
$('#me').text(function (oldText)
{
    return oldText.replace('{Name}', newName);
});
```

---

Reusable solution: use an existing templating implementation such as [`$.tmpl()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl) or [`mustache.js`](http://mustache.github.com/).

Answer (score -2):

```
var newText = "Tom";

newText = $("#me").text().replace("{Name}", newText );

$("me").text(newText);
```

Comment: After 1 year, 4 months, it's time to learn how to format your posts. :)

Comment: @Tom - Haha - true true. My excuse is no coffee yet.

Comment: @Matt: I [never knew that](http://www.ideone.com/N1Ldy)! Anyway, the "real" problem is that `text()` does getting, not setting.

Comment: @Matt - Didn't know that either. But you can set text with .text() http://api.jquery.com/text/